# passing a parameter in mips

Tags: java, mips

I want to translate this java code into MIPS. I get a syntax error. can you tell me what I am doing wrong.
Java

```
public static void setCount(int count)
{
 IntegerMath.count = count;
}
```

Mips

```
.globl setCount
#---------------
.text
setCount: #-----------------
lw count($0), $t0
jr $ra
#----------------------------- `
```

Java

```
System.out.println(IntegerMath.getCount());
int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
IntegerMath.setCount(a);
System.out.println(IntegerMath.getCount());`
```

Mips

```
#--------------------------------------------------
 jal getCount   #System.out.println(IntegerMath.getCount())  
 add $a0, $0, $v0  
 addi $v0, $0, 1   
 syscall  
 #-----------------------------------------------------  
 addi $v0, $0, 5 # readInt make new variable   
 syscall  
 add $t0, $0, $v0 #set t0 to value  
 #------------------------------------------  
 jal setCount   
add $a0, $0, $v0  
#-------------------------------   
addi $v0, $0, 1  
syscall  
#-------------------------    
 addi $sp, $sp, 4  
 lw $ra, 0($sp)  
 jr $ra
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error at?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line in your "setCount" method:    `lw count($0), $t0`

Load Word cannot be used in this way!
You can't use `count` as an operand.

If you are attempting to load `count`
 into $t0, do this: `lw $t0, count($0)`

I would encourage you to use the **[MARS MIPS Emulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/download.htm)**. It has built in error-checking that works, quite well.

**SIDE NOTE:**
Just a bit about your formatting. While it's not critical, it is syntactically more acceptable to format your `addi` statements as follows, for easier readability:

```
addi $v0, <some number>, $zero
```

Also, this one. `add $a0, $v0, $zero`